# AWS EC2: proFTPd Login Incorrect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I'm at a loss. I can't get anywhere with this.

Got a ubuntu 14.04 instance on ec2 AWS.
Trying to get the simple apache, ftp & mysql system up.

When attempting to login to proftpd 1.3.5rc3,  i always get incorrect login

I've tried vsftpd & proftpd but the issue is the same on both. 
I've set up ftp users with correct permissions, as well as logging in as the default session user (ubuntu for ubuntu instances - there is no password)

I've only managed to get anonymous to login correctly.

Is there a new bug? This set-up is not new to me, and i'm wasting a lot of time on this

(I'm only connecting localy so no external access needed)

I've tried this fix: [proftpd gives 'login incorrect' error](https://serverfault.com/questions/591861/proftpd-gives-login-incorrect-error)
- didn't resolve

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specific to this user's environment.

Comment: Please have a look at the [help], specifically the part about how to ask a good question. There's not even remotely enough information here to help you. We'd need your logs to start with - in fact, **you** should start with reading your server logs.

Comment: To be honest, i had an issue which i resolved myself, and posted my findings. clearly, at least 1 person has found this useful from the vote up.
i feel the criticism on this question (plus on other stack exchange pages) is unnecessary and not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 days later i find the issue:
By this point i'm back to vsftpd, and although i cannot confirm this will work for proftpd, it solved the exact issue i experienced in both.

under `/etc/vsftpd.conf`, you'll find a line `pam_service_name=vsftpd`. I changed this to `pam_service_name=ftp`.

I hope this helps someone

Comment: I assume you have `/etc/pam.d/ftp` then, 'cause I don't!

Comment: Nope, just vsftpd under that dir :S

Comment: is `pam` enabled inside of `vsftpd.conf`?

Comment: not that i know of. tbh i didn't even touch on `/etc/pam.d`. I have to admit, this resolve was pure trial & error for until yesturday night.

Answer (score 0):

By default, proftpd's mod_auth_pam module will look for a PAM service named "ftp"; this usually means an /etc/pam.d/ftp file.  However, on some systems/installations, rather than /etc/pam.d/ftp, there is an /etc/pam.d/ftpd file (or even /etc/pam.d/proftpd).

To get proftpd to look for a different PAM service name, you would use the following in your proftpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_auth_pam.c>
  # Tell mod_auth_pam to look for "ftpd" instead of "ftp"
  AuthPAMService ftpd
</IfModule>
```

Before you reach that point, though, you might want to make sure that PAM is really the issue.  You should first try telling proftpd to NOT use PAM, and see if your logins succeed:

```
<IfModule mod_auth_pam.c>
  AuthPAM off
</IfModule>
```

If your logins succeed, then you know that something in your PAM configuration is preventing the login; if not, then you know that something else, other than PAM, is the issue.